# How to disable a particular section like div for a specific user using JavaScript in .NetCore SignalR

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

I am developing planning poker. I am using .Net Core and its view for front as well as for server side comms. I am using SignalR Core. I am stuck at this situation-

Suppose I have 2 divs. One div-Div1 having the section where the cards selected by user will come. Second div-Div2 will have the range of cards from which users will pick their selection. Now, if users are logged in the group and they can see several cards like 0,1,2,3,4 etc.

Suppose User1 clicks on Card-0 so I want to hide the div containing the Cards----Div2 and wants to show Div1 to this User1 but at the same time if there is user2,since he has not chosen anything he will see the Div1-displaying the cards selected by User1(obviously not disclosing the number but an image that user1 has chosen something) and User2 will also see the Div2 fro where he can choose his cards also.

Lets say User2 now choose his card then User2's Div2 will also get hidden similarly like User1 and then a button with Show Card will appear since both users have chosen their cards.

I am getting stuck in this scenario only using JavaScript. In my case if a user is selecting the card, Div1 opens and Div2 hides but it does for all users whether the reaming users have not chosen their cards, which is wrong.

Comment: Is it necessary to have academic assignment?

Comment: No, not at all. Your deadline made it sound like an academic assignment, and if that was the purpose, I would have offered some advice about how much help one can obtain before the resulting work is not really one's own.

Comment: I would seek some advice and help on the above issue.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to hide the div containing the Cards----Div2 and wants to show Div1 to this User1 but at the same time if there is user2,since he has not chosen anything he will see the Div1-displaying the cards selected by User1

> In my case if a user is selecting the card, Div1 opens and Div2 hides but it does for all users whether the reaming users have not chosen their cards, which is wrong.

For above requirement, you should maintain a state "whose turn" that can indicate which user should be choosing and playing cards.

To display different UI on different users' side, can push the flag/data that indicates who is on turn from your hub method to connected users, then on SignalR client side code logic to check that flag and compare it with current user, if the user is on turn, show that particular section, otherwise hide that section.

Comment: I did not understand this. Can you show some examples?